# C++11 auto transform

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

i have this macro

```
#define DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO(iter) for (iter=s_blend_info.begin(); iter!=s_blend_info.end(); ++iter)
```

And this is the main function..

```
BLEND_ITEM_INFO* blend_info;
T_BLEND_ITEM_INFO::iterator iter;

DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO (iter)
{
    blend_info = *iter;
    if (blend_info->item_vnum == item->GetVnum())
    {

    }
}
```

What i want to do it's to get rid of this macro and to use auto.
But i can't understand how to use auto here...  I want to remove that macro, but what if i add auto in macro directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following, and nothing else:

```
for (const auto &blend_info:s_blend_info)
{
    if (blend_info->item_vnum == item->GetVnum())
    {

    }
}
```

And I mean, "nothing else" except that. No macros, no declaration of any iteration. No declaration of `blend_info`, the `auto` range iteration does it for you.

Comment: Why const? and why & ?   Is noth enought this ?     for (auto blend_info:s_blend_info)

Comment: Golden rule of thumb: unless you intend to modify something, explicitly declare it `const`. You're helping the compiler to optimize your code, and you prevent yourself from making unintentional bugs. And using a reference avoids making a redundant copy. Same reason why experienced C++ programmers write `void foo(const std::vector<int> &param);` instead of `void foo(std::vector<int> param);`

Comment: Thanks for explication @Sam Varshavchik

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. I modify to code and replace `s_blend_info` with `vector<int>` to get a compilable solution.

```
 int main()
 {
vector<int> s_blend_info;
int  blend_info;
vector<int>::iterator iter;
int item = 10;
for (auto iter = s_blend_info.begin(); iter != s_blend_info.end(); ++iter)
{
    blend_info = *iter;
    if (blend_info == item)
    {

    }
}
for ( auto &iter  : s_blend_info)
{
    if (blend_info == item)
    {

    }
}
DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO_GENERIC(s_blend_info, iter)
{
    blend_info = *iter;
    if (blend_info == item)
    {

    }
}
}

#define DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO(iter) for (iter=s_blend_info.begin(); iter!=s_blend_info.end(); ++iter)
#define DO_ALL_BLEND_INFO_GENERIC(container,iterator)  for (iterator=container.begin(); iterator!=container.end(); ++iterator)
```